# How to get user stories that does not have bugs in TFS to a Chart

Tags: tfs, project-management

I want to represent Sprint wise story count that does not occur any bugs in TFS dashboard. It is possible to get it via "Work items and direct links" But to get it to a chart it needs to be a Flat query. How can I get this?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get this?

Different charts could support different query types. You can use `Query Results` widget instead of `Chart for Work Items` widget which doesn't support query with links. You can get the count of the returned User Stories:

[image]

You can also see linked bugs via clicking the `>`:

[image]